# Angular increasing element's ID in post request

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have an issue in my Angular code, when I try to make **post request**. The main issue is with the ID. I'm initialising my listItems array and updating it when I add new list item into it. However, I cannot add an ID.

There are 2 issues:

1. I cannot add an ID via listItems array, because it is undefined,
   despite the fact, that I previously initialise it in OnInit
2. ID doesn't appear on the page, one when I refresh it. And when I try to delete item, it throws an error, however, when I refresh the page, I guess, Angular adds ID by itself, and it kinda works

Here is the code

list-main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListItem } from '../../models/list-item.interface';
import { ListDashboardService } from '../../list-dashboard.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'list-main',
    styleUrls: ['list-main.component.scss'],
    template: `
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Database To-do Angular</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            <list-form
                [blankListItem]="listItem"
                (addNewListItem)="addItem($event)">
            </list-form>
        </div>

        <!-- <div
            *ngFor="let item of listItems">
            {{ item.title | json }}
        </div> -->

        <div>
            <list-item
                *ngFor="let item of listItems"
                [listItem]="item"
                (delete)="deleteItem($event)">
            </list-item>
        </div>        
    `
})

export class ListMainComponent implements OnInit {
    listItems: ListItem[];
    listItem: ListItem;

    constructor(private listDashboardService: ListDashboardService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.listDashboardService
            .getAllListItems()
            .subscribe((data: ListItem[]) => this.listItems = data);

        this.listItem = {
            // id: this.listItems.length,
            id: undefined,
            title: '',
            isChecked: true
        }
    }

    addItem(listItem: ListItem) {
        console.log(this.listItem);

        this.listDashboardService
            .addListItem(listItem)
            .subscribe((data: ListItem) => {
                this.listItems.push(listItem);
            });

        console.log(this.listItems);
    }

    deleteItem(listItem: ListItem) {
        this.listDashboardService
            .deleteListItem(listItem)
            .subscribe((data: ListItem) => {
                this.listItems = this.listItems.filter(
                    (el: ListItem) => el.id !== listItem.id
                );
            });
    }
}
```

list-dashboard.service.ts

```
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { ListItem } from "./models/list-item.interface";

const LIST_API: string = '/api/listItems';

@Injectable()
export class ListDashboardService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getAllListItems(): Observable<ListItem[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(LIST_API)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    }

    addListItem(listItem: ListItem): Observable<ListItem> {
        return this.http
            .post(LIST_API, listItem)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    deleteListItem(listItem: ListItem): Observable<ListItem> {
        return this.http
            .delete(`${LIST_API}/${listItem.id}`)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: `.subscribe((data: ListItem) => {  this.listItems.push(listItem); });` - didn't you intend to push `data` rather than `listItem` to the items array?

Comment: @amakhrov , I guess, you're right. I'm still learning Angular, so, for now there will be mistakes like these, thank you very much

Comment: @amakhrov , could you explain, why do we pass data, not the listeItem?

Comment: I just assumed ID is generated at the backend and returned as a part of ListItem response from your service. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @amakhrov , well, I'm not sure about that, I'm using local database db.json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to generate id at the client side, rather than at the server.
All right, so first you need a way to produce unique ids.
A naive implementation could be

```
let lastId = 0;

export const getUniqueId = () => lastId++;
```

It might be sufficient for local testing, but not very robust (e.g. it restarts the sequence of ids upon page reload). If you want to do this in a real app, I'd suggest using smth like `uuid` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Ok, now you need to set unique id to each list item that you create:

```
class ListMainComponent {

   addItem(listItem: ListItem) {
        const listItemWithId = {
          ...listItem,
          id: getUniqueId()
        }

        this.listDashboardService
            .addListItem(listItemWithId)
            .subscribe(_ => {
                this.listItems.push(listItemWithId);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the listItems' length, and set it to the new item? I tried this, but it throws an error every time I take listItems.length, saying that it cannot take length property of undefined

Comment: It's possible but it doesn't make much sense. Say, you have 2 items in the list (ids 0 and 1). Then you remove the first one. The new list length is 1 again. Now you try to create a new item, and it gets the id=1 (currently length). As a result you have two items with the same id 1 in your list!

Comment: Didn't pay attention to this, you're right, thank you!